# How can I add a file to my volume without writing a new file to the host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a Next.js project inside docker-compose. To take advantage of hot-reloading, I'm mounting in the entire project to the Docker image as a volume.

So far, so good!

This is where things are starting to get tricky: For this particular project, it turns out Apple Silicon users need a `.babelrc` file included in their dockerized app, but NOT in the files on their computer.

All other users do not need a `.babelrc` file at all.

To sum up, this is what I'd like to be able to do:

- hot reload project (hence `./:/usr/src/app/`)
- have an environment variable write content to `/usr/src/app/.babelrc`.
- not have a `.babelrc` in the host's project root.

My attempt at solving was including the `.babelrc` under `ci-cd/.babelrc` in the host file system.

Then I tried mounting the file as a `volume` like  `- ./ci-cd/.babelrc:/usr/src/app/.babelrc`. But then a `.babelrc` file gets written back to the root of the project in the host filesystem.

I also tried include `COPY ./ci-cd/.babelrc /usr/src/app/.babelrc` within the Dockerfile, but it seems to be overwritten with docker-composes's `volume` property.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
   # Database image
   psql:
    image: postgres:13
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  # image for next.js project
  webapp:
    build: .
    command: >
      bash -c  "npm run dev"
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    expose:
      - 3002
    depends_on:
      - testing-psql
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
```

Comment: the `volume` connect the source folder from outside the docker to the destination folder in the inside.
it means that every change made in the destination folder in the docker will happen on the host.

Comment: Is there a solution involving a different config? Volume was the only way I could think of to meet the "hot-reload" requirement

Comment: maybe you can add the desiered file in a different location that is not mounted outside